# removing .php extension and creating dynamic url from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have following code for hiding php extension and redirecting user to a non .php url if user adds a .php extension in url for example domain.com/about.php should go to domain.com/about

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

But the problem is that I want to create dynamic url where domain.com/abc?slug=fased should be domain.com/abc/fased but its not working what to do I have used the code RewriteRule ^abc/([^.]+)$ abc?slug=$1 and RewriteRule is on

Comment: `/abc?slug=fased` isn't a valid end-point. Do you mean `/abc.php?slug=fased`?

Comment: Yes what you have said is correct I removed .php from the link cause as mentioned I have added a .php extension removal in htaccess

Comment: I have assumed that `abc` in your example is variable, just as `fased` is presumably variable. ie. `/<file>.php?slug=<slug-value>` - is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this instead in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to remove ".php" and optional "slug" query string
RewriteCond /%{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(/)(?:slug=([^/&]+))|/.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.php$ /$1%1%2 [QSD,R=301,END]

# Redirect to remove "slug" query string (when ".php" is not present on URL-path)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=([^/&]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ /$1/%1 [QSD,R=301,END]

# Rewrite to append ".php" extension
# Handles both "/about" (empty "slug") and "/abc/fased"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)(?:/([^/]+))?$ $1.php?slug=$2 [END]
```

In the directives you posted the `RewriteBase` directive was superfluous.

This handles both scenarios. ie. Requests for `/about` and `/abc/fased`. Requests for `/about` are internally rewritten with an *empty* `slug` URL parameter. However, this also means that `/about/foo` would also be a valid request (and serve `/about.php`). But that is really an issue with your "generalised" URL structure not these directives.

The first two rules handle the canonical redirects for SEO (you should already be linking to the canonical URLs internally). For example:

- `/about.php` redirects to `/about`
- `/abc?slug=fased` redirects to `/abc/fased`
- `/abc.php?slug=fased` redirects to `/abc/fased`

However, if any other URL parameters are present on the request then the *condition* won't match and there will be no redirect.

Clear your browser cache before testing and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: I have tried it as you have said with 302 but its not working

Comment: @AmbrishGoradia Sorry, the first rule would have resulted in a redirect loop (I assume that is what you mean by "not working"). I've updated my answer and revised the rules (now 3 rules, not two).

Comment: @AmbrishGoradia Sorry, the first rule would have resulted in a redirect loop. (I assume that is what you mean by "not working"?) I've updated my answer and revised the rules (now 3 rules, not two). Although your site should function OK without the first two rules (since you should already linking to the canonical URLs internally).

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good set of introductions to rewrite rules here: [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/157957)

One thing that's really useful to remember is that *rewrites* don't "make URLs pretty". The pretty URL is the **input**, and the ugly URL underneath is the **output**.

*Redirects* are the other way around, but they just tell the user to go somewhere else; the somewhere else has to work first.

With that in mind, your requirements are this:

1. a request for `abc/fased` should serve `abc.php?slug=fased`; and so on for any "slug"
2. a request for `def` should serve `def.php`, and so on for anything matches a PHP file *and isn't already covered by rule 1*
3. a request *directly* for `def.php` should tell the user to go to `def` instead

So:

```
# Rule 1
RewriteRule abc/(.*) abc.php?slug=$1 [END]

# Rule 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]

# Rule 3
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,END]
```

Only one rule can match each request, because they all have the `END` flag, and they'll be processed in order. You could put Rule 3 first, but it will only make a difference if you have a file called "abc/something.php" or "something.php.php".